# Templated member function doesn't accept any type of arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, template-function

I have the following classes:

```
template<class TYPE, class IDENTIFIER>
class Parameter
{
    TYPE typeValue;
    IDENTIFIER ID;
};

template<class IDENTIFIER>
class ParameterSystem
{
    template<typename TYPE>
    void AddParameter(Parameter<TYPE, IDENTIFIER> parameter, TYPE value);
};
```

However, whenever I try to use AddParameter, it says no function overload matches the argument list.I tried all sorts of possible combinations.For instance:

```
typedef unsigned int               ResourceIndex; //I use unsigned ints to reference resources in my other(resource system)
typedef unsigned int               DefaultParameterID;
typedef Parameter<ResourceIndex, DefaultParameterID>     ResourceParameter;
```

so then I use it like this:

```
ParameterSystem<DefaultParameterID> parameterSystem;
ResourceParameter param;
//do some stuff with param;
parameterSystem.AddParameter<ResourceIndex>(param, param.typeValue); //here it gives the error
```

And this doesn't work, Intellisense tells me it doesn't match the argument list, even tho it does.The argument list should be (Parameter, unsigned int) and that's what it is.What could I have done wrong?(For those interested, what AddParameter does is it takes the value of typeValue and sets it to a void pointer in a Map inside the parameter system and then it syncs the map key for that value with the ID of the parameter and the parameter also has a handle to it's parent parameter system, so from it's ID and a typecheck + typecast it can always get the parameter value in the system that responds to it's ID, but that shouldn't be relevant to the question I think...)

Comment: Is this your real code? The function is called `AddParameter` and you are calling `Add`. Also, Intellisense isn't the compiler. What does the *compiler* say about it?

Comment: oh yeah I edited it, sorry about that.

Comment: Where is `IDENTIFIER` in `void AddParameter(Parameter<TYPE, IDENTIFIER> ...`?

Comment: IDENTIFIER is inside param, it's the member ID.It's also the template argument of parameterSystem.

Comment: Please post the exact error the compiler gives.

Comment: OK the error went away when I used parameterSystem.AddParameter(param, param.typeValue); just like that, without the <ResourceIndex> part.Both Intellisense and the compiler are happy now.

Comment: Compiles with gcc, clang and icc if making your classes public.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding "typename" before the template type in the function's argument list:

```
void AddParameter(typename Parameter<TYPE, IDENTIFIER> parameter, TYPE value) {...}
```

Comment: `typename` is needed for nested names, this doesn't apply here.